# Correct use of Hashtable with custom class

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

This piece of code generates unexpected output.

```
Hashtable<Pair, Integer> results = new Hashtable<Pair, Integer>();
results.put(new Pair(0, 1), 2);
System.out.println("[DBG] " + results.containsKey(new Pair(0, 1)));
```

The output is `[DBG] false`. Why did `Hashtable` fail to register this element? Does it have something to do with the way I try to pass a `Pair` to the hashtable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to override `hashCode()` and `equals(..)` of your `Pair` class to indicate that two objects having the same numbers are equal. (Better let your IDE generate these 2 methods for you.)

`Hashtable` uses `hashCode()` to determine the hash of the object and look it up. When you create a new `Pair` instance, the default hashing implementation of `Object` generates a different hash, and hence your `Hashtable` fails to locate the pair (which is successfully inside)

And finally - use a `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable` . It's a newer and better implementation of the concept, and does not have unnecessary synchronization.

Comment: (And use `@Override` to avoid attempting to override the likes of `hashcode()` or `equals(Pair)`.)

Answer (score 2):

it is caused  by creating two different object by using `new Pair(0,1)`. So you  have two  choises for getting true :

The first one is you should implement hashCode and equals  methods of Pair class.

The second one use same object like this:

```
Hashtable<Pair, Integer> results = new Hashtable<Pair, Integer>();
Pair key=new Pair(0, 1)
results.put(key, 2);
System.out.println("[DBG] " + results.containsKey(key));
```